# How to write publishable-quality math and science papers?

Tags: research-process

I've learned it a bit, through a thesis paper (not PhD-level), and from reading good papers in good journals.  But I'm interested in best practices, specifically the things to implement in my style of writing to get my work up to publishable quality (assuming that the content is good enough)?

Answers which summarize tips from available, useful resources are welcome.

Comment: I'm VTC as off-topic because it *is* (IMO) a shopping question, but I like the premise of the question and wish it didn't have to be off-topic.

Comment: OP: I edited your question so that it may be a better fit for this site. Please, check to make sure I have maintained the spirit of your question. If you don't like the edits, you can always revert back to the previous version, or you can further edit the question.

Comment: @MadJack I don't think your edit really changes anything about the question. It's still either a "gimme a long list of resources" or "write me a whole book's worth of answer" question and that's still not a good fit for the Stack Exchange format.

Answer (score 7):

Two good primers specifically on the subject of mathematics, which is quite different from more empirical sciences in many of its conventions:

- Paul Halmos’s *[How to write mathematics](http://www2.math.uu.se/~takis/ETC/Halmos_howToWriteMath.pdf)* is a classic — still excellent, if slightly old-fashioned in some ways.
- Terence Tao’s blog post [*On writing*](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/advice-on-writing-papers/) collects and summarises links to some excellent advice from himself and others.

Answer (score 4):

A short but excellent reference is from the [George Whitesides group at Harvard](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/adma.200400767/abstract) which is available in the public domain.

It goes from outline to draft to finished paper in a few informative pages.

Comment: I like the general ideas there, but as the OP specified math (and science) I need to point out that a lot of the advice there is actively poor for someone writing a paper in math, at least without someone to point out the ways in which it needs to be different.

Answer (score 3):

- Donald Erwin Knuth, Tracy Larrabee, and Paul Morris Adrian Roberts, 
  [*Mathematical Writing*](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/reviewing-papers/knuth_mathematical_writing.pdf)
- Jerzy Trzeciak, *Mathematical English Usage Dictionary*, 2016
- Jerzy Trzeciak, *Writing Mathematical Papers in English - A Practical Guide*, 2005
- Three mistakes that people should stop making? 1. Worrying too much about formatting and not enough about content. 2. Worrying too much about formatting and not enough about content. 3. Worrying too much about formatting and not enough about content. (Source: Leslie Lamport, [*How (La)TeX changed the face of Mathematics*](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/lamport-latex-interview.pdf).)

Answer (score 2):

Steven G. Krantz's [A Primer of Mathematical Writing, Second Edition](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.04888) is freely available on arxiv.