# Good research paper in mathematics

Tags: publications, mathematics

This question may seem like vague but I am still asking... What does make a research paper 'good' in pure mathematics ? I am asking this question independent of the journal where it gets published or the number of citation that the paper has. Is this depth of the content or some ingenious/out of the box approach ? Great mathematician Paul Erdos used the term 'the proof' from 'the book' in order to classify such papers. I personally feel the depth and the ingenious are somewhat contradictory because why did mathematicians then care about an elementary proof of prime number theorem as there was already proof of that using complex analysis ! I am just giving an example. Is it necessary to have a perfect proof each theorem in pure mathematics ?

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/124335/what-are-some-characteristics-of-top-quality-research-work-in-math https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/95501/how-to-write-publishable-quality-math-and-science-papers

Comment: This isn't really a question about academia, it is a question about mathematics and aesthetics. But also, I think it is too subjective to be a good question for a StackExchange site.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can hardly get a better answer than the paper “[What is good mathematics?](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0702396.pdf)” by Terence Tao: a world-famous mathematician answering precisely your question.

As you can see, "good mathematics" is presented there as a multi-dimensional concept: a paper can be good because it shows great problem-solving, and/or because it shows a masterful use of known techniques, and/or because it contains great new discoveries, and so on. I guess you will enjoy the reading.

As for your last line:

> Is it necessary to have a perfect proof each theorem in pure mathematics ?

...well, it depends on what you mean by "perfect". The proof have to be rigorous, clear and complete, of course. But many great papers contain proofs that later have been simplified and made more direct, elementary or general.

Comment: That is a great link, but please note that we discourage link-only answers. Please add a brief summary, or at least a description of what people are clicking on.

Comment: Yeah, sure. Done.

Comment: @AlessandroDellaCorte Really we want answers here to stand on their own as much as possible. Outside references are great, but if someone has to follow a link to get *any* value out of the answer, it's not really a SE-quality answer. Think about your answer if the link were to rot away: all it provides is that someone answered the question somewhere else. That's not enough to be useful.

Comment: @BryanKrause your criticism might be reasonable in a generic situation of a link answer to a Se question, but in the current situation, Tao’s article does in fact answer OP’s precise question, and is stored on arXiv, making your concern about link rot moot. Sometimes a link answer really is the best possible answer and there isn’t anything more to say.

Comment: @DanRomik Certainly it would be possible to summarize the reference and cite it properly. As-is, it reads like a clickbait headline: "One Simple Trick That The Best Living Mathematician..."

Comment: @BryanKrause yes, I agree that characterizing people as “best living [X]” is distasteful. And also agree about the citation.

Comment: With no disrespect to Tao, I am extremely uncomfortable with people throwing around terms such as "the best living mathematician", not least because I encounter a lot of posets that are not totally ordered

Comment: @YemonChoi: Reminds me of a job interview where the hiring committee (most of them mathematicians) kept asking me for my "best" paper, for the "most" important thing when supervising a PhD student, and so on. Each of my answers started with "Ah, you're again asking for the largest element in a poset which is not totally ordered..." (Maybe I should add that I didn't get the job - but this was presumably due to different reasons...)

Comment: Funny thing: I agree with your criticism. I was half-joking in the answer, but maybe here it is not so appropriate. 
Later I’ll try to improve the answer, even though the effect I liked at first will be lost…

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the answer to improve the bits which were controversial, hope you don’t mind.

Comment: @DanRomik Sure. I added other things.

Comment: @JochenGlueck that’s a cool story. But is it possible you didn’t get the job because you failed to make a distinction between a poset that isn’t totally ordered and a poset that doesn’t have a greatest element…?

Answer (score 0):

A good research paper (actually, an excellent one) is a paper that not only solves a given problem (proves a given theorem), but also provides insight that might be useful more generally.

It isn't entirely the *existence* of a correct proof that matters, though the first proof of a long known problem is celebrated. It is more the nature of the proof.

For example, the Four Color Theorem (when I was young: the Four Color Hypothesis) is unsatisfactory to a mathematician, depending on computer analysis of a large number of cases. A clean, mathematical, proof of a few pages would be not only a breakthrough, but would let people think about similar (and even not similar) problems in a new way.

Mathematicians seek insight. It isn't until you have quite a lot of insight into one or more classes of problems that you are really a mathematician. It gives you the ability to postulate, somewhat accurately, what might be true. Once you have such ideas you know where to put your efforts. But without that you are just fishing in muddy waters.

I don't think I really measured up at the time I earned my doctorate, though my dissertation was very interesting (to a few people). But I did develop that understanding of the nature of mathematics over time.

---

### [Four Color Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem): Any planar map can be colored with four or fewer colors so that adjacent regions have different colors. Regions that only touch at a single point can have the same color.

Caveat: I haven't followed up with the Four Color Theorem in years, so there may have been important advances that I don't know about. But we were happy, if unsatisfied, with the first proof.

Comment: What is interesting about the proof of the 4CTh is how so many mathematicians felt obliged to lie about it. The concept behind the proof is beautiful but the proof itself is ugly - *but they didn’t think they were allowed to say that* and instead made up fatuous excuses about “the reliability of computer-assisted proofs”. It is refreshing to see that we are now allowed to say it out loud: mathematics is about beauty and delight.

Comment: @MartinKochanski, Interesting that you say "lie". Why is that? I have no qualms with computer assisted proofs. I just find them less elegant than pure math.

Answer (score -1):

Try not to think about “mathematicians” because they are an imaginary abstraction. Think of real people instead, starting with yourself.

To get you started, are my criteria for a good mathematical paper:

1. I am paying for this paper. Not in money, but in time.
2. If I have wasted my time, I can’t ask the author for a refund.
3. So the paper has to be worth it.

(Reading papers is a gamble and it is the job of a journal editor to improve the odds.)

So at different times, a “good” paper could be:

- A first proof (even if ugly).
- A proof of a certain kind (eg. elementary rather than advanced).
- A proof with reason behind it, so that you can see *why* it works, not just *that* it works.
- A presentation showing general principles beneath a more complicated surface.

One can multiply the examples but the key point to remember is that mathematics is the pursuit of beauty - there would be no point in doing it if it weren’t - and that when it comes to matters of beauty, you are the judge. (If you see beauty where others don’t then you have to teach them, of course - it is the task of every artist in every field, throughout the ages.)

If there were definite rules for what makes a good mathematical paper “this one is worth 100 milliEulers”) then machines could do it all - write the papers, and read them too.